# How to access a ClassPath ressource from a jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, path

I am writing a Spring Boot web app.

In my app I need to be able to download a zip file that is packaged into the executable application .jar.

I am using ClassPathResource to load the stream of that file:

```
Resource applier=new ClassPathResource("applier/com.itnsa.patch.applier-1.0.25-SNAPSHOT-package.zip");
if (applier.exists()) {//do stuff}
```

The zip file is located in /src/main/resources/applier.

In some other classes of my app I already use this method to retrieve some .txt files from /src/main/resources/exception and everything works correctly. When I try to access the zip the exists method returns false.

What am I doing wrong in accessing the zip archive? How can I achieve this?

Comment: `ClassPathResource("/applier")` should be enough. No need to show wchich jar file should be used. The jar should be added to classpost when the app is run.

Comment: problem is that i can't access the zip file that is on applier/myZip.zip the exists() method yields false

Comment: Have you tried to start the path from `/`?

Comment: Try to unzip your speing-boot jar and make sure that the resource is really there.

Comment: yes it is there, at the path where it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Resource applier=new ClassPathResource("applier/com.itnsa.patch.applier-1.0.25-SNAPSHOT-package.zip");
if (applier.exists()) {//do stuff}
```

It should work, i tried same file name and same folder structure it returns true, Make sure that jar file is on class path.
If you are doing/working it with any IDE make sure jar file is on classpath.
There is also another way you can utilize given below, but this is not the case for you

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fileName.zip"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: I really don't get why it didn't work before, but now it works, all I did was a `clean install ` in maven

Comment: it sometimes happens, but now glad to here that it's working!!! great and cheers!!